# Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to 'false'

Tags: c#, sonarqube, null-coalescing-operator

During analysis by SonarQube we are seeing many examples of this warning

> Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to 'false';
>   some subsequent code is never executed.

So one example where this is happening is - for the given code...

```cs
    if (components?.ContainsKey(machineType) ?? false)
    {
        return components[machineType];
    }

    throw new ArgumentException($"There is no available configuration for {machineType}!");
```

... we get...

[image]

We are using the C# null coalesce to short cut null-checks so that providing `components`, which is a Dictionary, is not `null`, and `components` *does* contain the the key specified by `machineType` then we return the value in the `components` Dictionary for the `machineType` key.

Otherwise if  `components` is null, **or** if the Dictionary *does not* contain the key, then the expression evaluates to `false` and we don't enter the block and return a value, but we throw an exception instead.

Please can someone explain as to why SonarQube is complaining about this. If we rewrite this to use the "old fashioned" verbose-style of null-checking and `&&`ing then SonarQube is a happy-bunny.

Is it just that SonarQube does not understand the `??` operator?

Or is it that we are simply abusing the `?.` or `??` operators in statements like this?

Comment: You could replace it with `components?.ContainsKey(machineType) == true` since `null == true` will return false. I've never used SonarQube, but I assume it should be happy with that?

Comment: I think the problem is just you said "it is just that SonarQube does not understand the ?? operator"

Comment: Maybe because `components` is always null?

Comment: @John - I have checked that approach and it is good with SonarQube, so we will implement that.

@Nurhan - Quite possibly!

@Sweeper - Nope, `components` is DEFINITELY not null in most code paths, but could be null, under certain conditions hence the check.

Comment: Wild guess: is it possible that on all paths where `components` is not null it definitely doesn't contain `machineType`? This can happen, if the same or similar condition was already handled before. The fact that SonarQube is OK with the alternative goes against this hypothesis though.